# how to give array a name

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have an array that contains both english and russian data. I converted the array to json like this

```
echo json_encode(array(' list'=>$posts));
```

it converted the array but did not displayed the russian data properly, output was something like this

```
{" list":[{"id":"1","type":"\u0439\u0446\u0443\u043a\u0435\u043d","name":"","description":"","location":"","latitude":"","longitude":""},
{"id":"3","type":"","name":"Cafe","description":"","location":"","latitude":"","longitude":""}]}
```

to maintaing the russian data i converted the array in a different way, like this

```
echo json_encode($posts, 256);
```

and received the following output. conversion was done correctly but the problem is that the array did not got the array name "list" as it got in the previous output.

```
[{"id":"1","type":"йцукен","name":"","description":"","location":"","latitude":"","longitude":""},
{"id":"3","type":"","name":"Cafe","description":"","location":"","latitude":"","longitude":""}
```

I tried to combining both the method but that also didn't work. can anyone tell how i can get the array name in the second method

Comment: 1. What's the difference between them that makes you in stuck? 2. Why do you need `stripslashes`? Do you realize that it breaks the `json` structure? 3. What is `256`?

Comment: Your json_encoded data was changed by something. You should get `\u0439\u0446\u0443\u043a\u0435\u043d`

Comment: @zerkms  i didn't knew that stripslashes does so, i will remove them. and the difference in both is that the second method helps me to print data in russian language while the first one is not doing so

Comment: Because in second case you didn't specify any key  so just like your first case you specify the key name as list `echo json_encode(array(' list'=>$posts),256);`

Comment: @Tintu C Raju i got the array name thru ur method, but now my russian language is being displayed as Ð¹Ñ†ÑƒÐºÐµÐ½

Comment: " while the first one is not doing so" --- JSON has nothing to do with language. What if you explain the **original task** instead? Your current solution just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Ja͢ck earlier i had used PHP_JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE but it used to give me error:  json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given.. so i used the numeric form, and it helps me in fetching the russian data properly

Comment: @kavi The constant was introduced in PHP 5.4, so if you're using an older version than that I would also recommend upgrading your PHP installation.

Comment: @zerkms its not json that converts the language but by using 256 i am able to display the russian data properly in json array. if i am not using 256 (as in the first method) then the russian text is not getting displayed properly

Comment: @Ja͢ck my php version is 5.5.21 CGI

Comment: Oops, I meant `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`, sorry.

Comment: @kavi: well, it's more a representation problem, not encoding. You don't need that 256. Your current solution solves not the root of the issue, but the consequences. I'm using `json_encode` with russian alphabet as well and I never used any specific flags to display it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it should be easy to spot the difference when the statements are put side-by-side:

```
echo json_encode(array(' list'=>$posts));
echo json_encode($posts, 256);
```

What's being passed as the first argument is different, so at the very minimum you need this:

```
echo json_encode(array(' list'=>$posts), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Second, `"\u0439\u0446\u0443\u043a\u0435\u043d"` is equivalent to `"йцукен"`, so unless you have a very good reason for this, it's best to just work with the default options.